# Trigger on closing the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

How to set a trigger when a close button is pressed on the spreadsheet.
is it actually possible?
The script I am using is google apps script

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers) a list of triggers available on Google Scripts.